# xampp in windows 7 has problems with long directory names

Tags: php, windows, xampp

i am using xampp under windows 7 and having problems with rename(); when the directory has over 69 characters, when i try this on my linux godaddy account it seems like it work.

why am i having issues in windows when going through xampp's apache php?
how can i fix this?

```
rename('../../../../../myFolder_small/American_Craft/Drawn_from_Clay_story_Deborah_Bishop_photo_Paul_Scala_American_Craft_/Drawn from Clay_story Deborah Bishop_photo Paul Scala 2_American Craft june july 10.jpg', '../../../../../myFolder_small/American_Craft/Drawn_from_Clay_story_Deborah_Bishop_photo_Paul_Scala_American_Craft_/81f8b1e81a29b9c6f997b2d869e5f6d8b461c32d.jpg');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows won't let you name a file if the absolute path of the filename exceeds 260 chars ([source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/File-names-and-file-name-extensions-frequently-asked-questions)). Based on your example that could be the problem.

Comment: no, sadly. Or use a shorter docroot path, working with junctions and such.